# Rails4でSCSSを使っている場合にコンパイルされた結果はdevelopmentの場合、どこのディレクトリに置かれているのでしょうか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails

RailsでSCSSを使っています。コンパイルされた結果はどのディレクトリにあるのでしょうか？
開発環境（development）を想定しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

development においては、特に設定を変更していないのであれば、コンパイル結果はディスク上には存在しません。リクエストがあるたびに、ソースと中間キャッシュを用いて毎回コンパイルしています。中間キャッシュは Rails 4.2 では tmp/cache/assets/development 下に生成されますが、どのキャッシュファイルがどのソースに対応するかなどは、一般的には言えません。

コンパイル結果をディスク上に得たいのであれば、以下のコマンドで public/assets 下に出力が可能な場合があります。プロジェクトの設定や作りによってはうまくいかない場合があるのと、出力後にソースを更新した場合に反映されなくなることがあるのに気をつけてください。

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development
```

余談ですが、これをクリアするには以下を実行するか、もしくは通常ならば public/assets を削除すれば良いでしょう。

```
rake assets:clobber
```